# Code::Blocks Can't compile application

Tags: c, codeblocks

This is my hello world code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I'm trying to run application I'm getting an error:

```
Target uses an invalid compiler; run aborted
```

So I went to Settings->Compiler->Toolchain Executables, and I selected `C:\MinGW\bin`, I have also tried  `C:\MinGW` and I still get the same error.

I have installed Code::Blocks with mingw from the official Code::Blocks site.

Please help, I want start learning C but I can't...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You either have the wrong compiler selected in your project's build options **OR** you don't have executables set in your compiler settings.

### To select your compiler in your project:

First, go to the `Project` menu and select `Build options`:

[image: Project menu]

Then, in the `Build options` dialog, select the compiler you have set up as described in your question:

[image: Build Options dialog]

### To change your compiler's executables:

Go to `Settings` and then `Compiler`:

[image: Settings->Compiler]

Then select `Toolchain Executables`:

[image: Toolchain Executables]

and fill in your executable names:

[image]

Comment: I can't select select .exe application, Only folder, and it doesn't work.

Comment: @SammyMe ok, give me a couple of minutes and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Fixed, now I know what you mean, Thanks mate.

Comment: @SammyMe what was the solution?

Comment: @SammyMe ~~I have updated the answer -- is that the solution that you used?~~ Ah, I see what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, figured it was Environment error, download the mingw-setup.exe file from CodeBlocks ide. After installation 
Go to Settings>>Compiler>>Reset Defaults

Answer (score 0):

I'm using windows 10 and was having the same problem. I used the Setting>Compiler> Toolchain executables. Auto-detect button. It's at the end of the Compiler's installation directory: path box. After clicking the button it was set to C:\Program files(x86)\codeblocks\mingw