# I can't compile c++ program in code blocks. It gives me error

Tags: c++, codeblocks

In code blocks when I am running program (single Hello world program).

Here is code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It gave me an error:

```
Project/Target: "test - Debug":
The compiler's setup (GNU GCC Compiler) is invalid, so Code::Blocks cannot find/run the compiler.
Probably the toolchain path within the compiler options is not setup correctly?!
Do you have a compiler installed?
Goto "Settings->Compiler...->Global compiler settings->GNU GCC Compiler->Toolchain executables" and fix the compiler's setup.

Tried to run compiler executable 'C:\MinGW/bin/mingw32-gcc.exe', but failed!

Skipping...
Nothing to be done (all items are up-to-date).
```

Comment: Did you install a compiler? Code::Blocks is an IDE. It doesn't come with a compiler.

Comment: Go [here](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26). Download *codeblocks-17.12-setup.exe*. **Note:** *The codeblocks-17.12-setup.exe file includes Code::Blocks with all plugins.*

Comment: the C language is NOT C++,  The question is about C++.  Strongly suggest removing the `c` 'tag'

Comment: the `gcc` compiler is for C programs.  Strongly suggest using `g++` or `gpp`

Comment: If you have installed MinGW as it seems, does it work from the command line? If not, what is the error message?

Comment: Deciding which language you are using should be first step. If you want to use C++, use a C++ compiler and use C++ tag. C tag is not related.

Comment: @user3629249 GCC is Gnu Compiler Collection, which can be used for many languages including C++.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code::Blocks Can't compile application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558261/codeblocks-cant-compile-application)

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the mingw setup, that includes a compiler with your IDE